# Access to documentation of a decorated function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am developing an API through which I am passing to the user list of functionalities of a module with the documentations of each function. In order to access the documentation I used to do:

```py
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Foo documentation is here!
    """
    return None

print(foo.__doc__)
# Foo documentation is here!
```

Now that I added a decorator for some of those functions, the `__doc__` returns `None` since the decorator function doesn't have any documentation.

```py
def decor_func(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

@decor_func
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Foo documentation is here!
    """
    return None

print(foo.__doc__)
# None
```

Is there any way that I can have access to decorated function's documentation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps?

Comment: use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in your decorator!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, it is helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update the `__doc__` attribute of the `wrap` function:

```py
def decor_func(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # Set the decorated function `__doc__` attribute
    wrap.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    return wrap

@decor_func
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Foo documentation is here!
    """
    return None

print(foo.__doc__)
# Foo documentation is here!
```

However, the best approach is to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), as allows you to also copy additional attributes such as the original name, module and annotations:

```
import functools

def decor_func(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

@decor_func
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Foo documentation is here!
    """
    return None

print(foo.__doc__)
# Foo documentation is here!
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. Will accept it as soon as SO let me to!

Answer (score 2):

Note, as others have pointed out, you should use `functools.wraps` so that your wrapper "looks" like the function it is wrapping, and adds the wrapped fucntion to a `__wrapped__` attribute. However, note, you can always introspect the wrapper's closure to retrieve a reference to the original function, since it is a free variable in the wrapper and thus will be stored in the closure:

```
>>> def decor_func(func):
...     def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
...         return func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return wrap
...
>>> @decor_func
... def foo(*args, **kwargs):
...     """
...     Foo documentation is here!
...     """
...     return None
...
>>> foo.__closure__
(<cell at 0x10e69da90: function object at 0x10e83a700>,)
```

So,

```
>>> foo.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__doc__
'\n    Foo documentation is here!\n    '
```

But again, you should use `functools.wraps` to begin with. The above might help if you have no control over the decorator though.